# Angular 2 unit tests/Karma test runner: Coverage reported only of "included: true" karma-test-shim

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, electron, karma-coverage

I only get test coverage results of any {included: true} file, which in my case is only karma-test-shim.js. I can't make my test files {included: true}, because SystemJs is supposed to load them in the karma-test-shim. Trying to make my test files {included: true} results in the "anonymous System register calls are not allowed" error. My tests run fine with {included: false}. Using SystemJS to load test files in karma-test-shim, and making test files {included: false}, is the standard format followed by Angular 2 github repos, including the angular2-quickstart repo.

I do use "system" as the module format in my tsconfig.json file instead of "commonjs", and the Electron browser instead of Chrome (via the karma-electron NPM package), alongwith a one line Electron require shim in the karma-test-shim file above the **karma**.loaded line - all of this together enables "requires" of node modules like fs, path, or installed ones, to work in tests without pre-bundling. My application is a desktop application with Electron and Angular 2.

Apart from these differences, I have exactly the same testing setup (karma.conf.js and karma-test-shim.js) as https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed.

Here is my basic karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: 'src/', // all the files in the files config  parameter, are searched for relative to this path

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: files, // the files parameter exported from another file

        preprocessors: {'*.js': ['coverage']},

        reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'], //report to console

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        browsers: ['Electron'],

        singleRun: false // true is necessary for CI. Set to false so  the browser is on long enough to debug.

    })
}
```